# TypeError: X is not a function when calling custom hook

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks, react-google-login

I'm trying to write a simple login page. I want to pass the token generated from the login component to my auth component which will set context, and then send the user back to the home page after login. I'm running into an issue trying to call the useAuthContext hook inside the handleLogin element. Here's I think the relevant code:

```
const authState = useAuthState();
const handleLogin = accessToken => {
  console.log(accessToken);
  authState({ accessToken });
  history.push("/");
}
```

handleLogin gets called with the onSuccess handler in the login component.

I get an error that authState is not a function.

I've looked at code samples that seem to work just like this when needing to call a hook inside an arrow function, so not sure what I'm doing wrong.

Edit: Problem is staring at me in the face.
authState is not a value under my Context Provider. Problem solved.

Comment: what is returned from `useAuthState`? I would suspect the return type is not what you expect. for instance, state would be `const [state, setState] = useState()`, because the React hook `useState` returns an array of items.

Comment: According to the [docs](https://github.com/csfrequency/react-firebase-hooks/tree/edab3f3f3b5ec01c8aafcc6096755dfcc69e4408/auth#useauthstate) it seems to be `const [user, loading, error] = useAuthState(auth);`. This hook is supposed to let you change your UI if the user's auth status changes.

Comment: useAuthState shouldn't return anything, not using firebase. The function takes the token, verifies it against the backend, and then uses SWR to force the frontend to revalidate on change. If I return the user to the homepage it should successfully log them in.

Comment: If `useAuthState` doesn't return anything then why do you assign a variable to it? This part of your code snippet `const authState = useAuthState();`